# Go build constraints to run if none set

Tags: go, go-testing, go-build

I have many classes of test, which are marked with build constraints, e.g.:

```
//go:build all || (!foo && !bar && !baz && quux)
```

for the test class `quux`. This is okay, as far as it goes, but what I'd really rather have is constraints such that the class `quux` runs for these commands (in the correct directory):

```
$ go test
$ go test ./...
$ go test ./... -tags quux
```

but not for

```
$ go test ./... tags foo
```

The actual list of test classes is twenty-plus, so

```
//go:build all || quux || (!foo && !bar && !baz &&...
```

is not a good option. If there's some way to set the default value of `-tags`, so that running `go test ./...` without explicitly passing a `-tags` argument defaults to `-tags all` (or even if that's possible but only for bare `go test` rather than with `./...`), that would be good enough.

Comment: There are never no build tags, because every build has implicit tags provided for OS & arch.

Comment: I'm aware. That's not relevant.

Comment: Then perhaps you should edit your question, which currently reads "Go build constraints to run if none set". The scenario "if none set" is not possible.

Comment: No, it's correct as stated.